# Erro Evento ListView ( ListView1UpdateObjects ), para mostrar ou ocultar item. ( Delphi firemonkey )

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey

Se alguém puder me ajudar, estou com um problema em um método de um `ListView`, o método é o `TForm13.ListView1UpdateObjects` nele eu faço o seguinte procedimento: verifico o valor de um item para decidir se mostro ou não um item e concateno o item a ser mostrado.

Segue o código:

```
    procedure TForm13.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);

var
   ItemText_parcelar_cartao : TListItemText;
   ItemText_valor_parc : TListItemText;
   ItemText_quant_parc : TListItemText;
   concat : TListItemText;
begin


    ItemText_parcelar_cartao := AItem.Objects.FindObject('Text_parcelar_cartao') as TListItemText;
    ItemText_valor_parc := AItem.Objects.FindObject('Text_valor_parcela') as TListItemText;
    ItemText_quant_parc := AItem.Objects.FindObject('Text_quant_parcela') as TListItemText;
    concat := AItem.Objects.FindObject('Text_concat') as TListItemText;




    if ItemText_parcelar_cartao.text = 'sim' then
    begin

       concat.visible := true;
       concat.text := 'ou ' + ItemText_quant_parc.text + 'x de ' + ItemText_valor_parc.text;

    end
    else
       concat.visible := false;

end;
```

O problema é o seguinte: este `ListView` está ligado em um `FDMemTable` principal, quando carrego o `FDMemTable` com os dados inicialmente, tudo funciona bem, e em outra etapa eu adiciono mais registros ao `FDMemTable` principal vindos de um `FDMemTable` auxiliar, com a seguinte função:

```
FDMemTable_produto_por_desc.AppendData(FDMemTable_produto_por_desc_pagina.Data, true);
```

Quando adiciono os novos registros, a função `TForm13.ListView1UpdateObjects` é executada, e é nesse momento que ocorre o erro, a variável `ItemText_parcelar_cartao.text` fica vazia e não recebe o valor do campo do `FDMemTable`, e por consequência ele não testa e não concatena corretamente.

Comment: Cassiano, e se você tentar jogar o texto para uma variável string, assim: `str := AItem.Objects.FindObject('Text_parcelar_cartao').asString;` Ele viria o valor corretamente sem precisar mover para uma variável do tipo `TListItemText`, mas sim diretamente para uma `string`?

Comment: Ou então `... AItem.Objects.FindObject('Text_parcelar_cartao').Text;`. A idéia é encontrar o objeto já pegando a string localizada.

Comment: Ok... Rodrigo, fiz assim :  str_parc := TListItemText(AItem.Objects.FindObject('Text_parcelar_cartao')).Text;  pois .text direto não funciona , mas não resolveu o problema, a variável continua vazia.

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Tenta desta forma para pegar o valor.

```
var
  item: TListItemText;

begin
  item := AItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Text_parcelar_cartao');

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola eu tentaria usar o valor como condição ou passar para uma outra varivel que nao seja Tlistitemtext. Usa o ListItemtext apenas para apresentar os resultados e nao como condicao.

Answer (score 0):

> O problema é o seguinte: este ListView está ligado em um FDMemTable principal, quando carrego o FDMemTable com os dados inicialmente, tudo funciona bem, e em outra etapa eu adiciono mais registros ao FDMemTable principal vindos de um FDMemTable auxiliar,

Ligado como? LiveBindings? Se for tira essa amarração e faz o update via código

Seu código em si não tem problemas lógicos, teoricamente se não existir valor para a variável `ItemText_parcelar_cartao.Text`, simplesmente ela ficará oculta. Já que você informou que após o Append do FDMemTable que tá dando o problema, acredito que a culpa tá antes de jogar os dados na lista. Se você usa LiveBindings vai ter problema o tempo todo.